# Is it possible to pass or replace part of control name?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

first of all I would like you to brace yourselves.
I have started programming only around 6 weeks ago. I do apologize if anything facepalm worthy follows.

I was wondering if it is possible to pass only part of a control name?

This is the idea:

I have two teams, Class is set up like this:

```
public class Team
{
    int    _established; //could be string
    string _name;
    double _best
}
//Snip
```

I have 2 sets of forms, both identical for input, but the only difference are the names:

```
//Team 1
    team1Year.Text = "";
    team1Name.Text = "";
    team1Numericupdown.Value = 0;
//Team 2
    team2Year.Text = "";
    team2Name.Text = "";
    team2Numericupdown.Value = 0;
```

So, it is essentially the same. I was wondering if it is possible to create a method that would do the following:

```
//Snip
Team team1 = new Team()
Team team2 = new Team()
//Not specific to problem, values can be anything
team1.estYear = 2008;
team1.Name = "Teamname1";
team1.Best = 137.8;

team2.estYear = 2009;
team2.Name = "GenericName";
team2.Best = 134.3;




private void HowToMethod(string tm, Team values)
{
    //so it would become like this - replace team1 and team2 with an argument
    tmYear.Text = values;
    tmName.Text = values;
    tmNumericupdown.Value = values;
}
```

And in practice:

```
HowToMethod(team1, team1.estYear)
//Output: team1Year.Text = 2008;

HowToMethod(team1, team1.Name)
//Output: team1Name.Text = Teamname1;

HowToMethod(team2, team2.Best)
//Output: team2Numericupdown.Value = 134.3;
```

This is not mandatory, I was just wondering if such thing is possible. I am fine with not having solution to this. There are different control/forms present, not all are the same, but they belong to the same "group" by name.
I hope it was not too confusing.

**EDIT1:**
**So i have tried to be less confusing. Again, I do apologize for the facepalm. English is also not my first language, which also doesn't help. Anyways, here it goes:**

This works, but to me it looks like repetitive code.
I was wondering if there is a simpler solution
...that is not an advanced topic

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Just one example. It's about manipulating Forms/Controls via code
    //Lock Team1's controls
    team1Year.Enabled = false;
    team1Name.Enabled = false;
    team1NumericUpDown.Enabled = false;
    //Lock Team 2's Controls
    team2Year.Enabled = false;
    team2Name.Enabled = false;
    team2NumericUpDown.Enabled = false;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Another button unlocks
    //Unlock Team1's controls
    team1Year.Enabled = true;
    team1Name.Enabled = true;
    team1NumericUpDown.Enabled = true;
    //Unlock Team 2's Controls
    team2Year.Enabled = true;
    team2Name.Enabled = true;
    team2NumericUpDown.Enabled = true;
}
```

Ok, so the above works - manually pick the controls we want to disable
Can it be *something like* this:
Apologies if not using proper object types

```
private void MyMethod(int X, bool isItEnabled)
{
//This feels so, so wrong
    Control ctrl = sender as Control;
    team{X}Year.Enabled ;
    team{X}Name.Enabled = {isItEnabled};            
    team{X}NumericUpDown.Enabled = {isItEnabled};  
}

//In action:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

MyMethod(1, false)
//Would mean/become:
    team{1}Year.Enabled = {false};
    team{1}Name.Enabled = {false};
    team{1}NumericUpDown.Enabled = {false};

//Or if the method was implemented differently:

private void MyMethod(string prefix, bool isItEnabled)
{
    {prefix}Year.Enabled ;
    {prefix}Name.Enabled = {isItEnabled};            
    {prefix}NumericUpDown.Enabled = {isItEnabled};            
}
```

//In action:

```
MyMethod(team2, true)
//Would mean:
    {team2}Year.Enabled = {true};
    {team2}Name.Enabled = {true};
    {team2}NumericUpDown.Enabled = {true};
```

So the arguments passed could replace only part of the control name
if they have a shared sequential name

In conclusion:

** Is it possible to introduce a variable to replace part of code for modularity**:
//Making the idea into a method would be secondary
could become:

X = "team1";

```
Properties.Settings.Default.{X}Totals;
{X}Year.Text = "";
{X}Name.Text = "";
{X}Whatever.Text = "";
{X}NumericUpDown.Value = 135;
```

I know it works with Classes:

```
private void TeamStuff(Team teamID, string value1, string value2)
{
teamID.Year = value;
teamID.Name = value;
//...etc
}
//then
TeamStuff (team1, "sample", "GenericName");
//becomes
team1.Year = "sample";
team1.Name = "GenericName";
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do. Your input come from a form, and you then create 2 instances of Team with the values you took from the form right? So what is the purpose of the method you're trying to implement?

Comment: Edit: My question is not so much about the method, but if it is possible to  modularize or use variables as part of control name
===
I have edited my original post, i hope it is enough to clarify. The purpose of the method would be manipulating seemingly repetitive code (with only difference between them would be the  "prefix" used - team1, team2...etc, but same fields otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really dont know what you are trying to do, and i guess that there may be better ways to do it,but to answer your specific question, here is the implementation of `HowToMethod`

```
private void HowToMethod(string tm, Team values)
{
    var yearControlName = tm + "Year";
    foreach(var ctrl in Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            var tb = (ctrl as TextBox);
            if (tb.Name == yearControlName)
                tb.Text = values.EstYear.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Its only for showing the `EstYear` but is enough for you to try yourself and implement the rest,

P.S. Surely this code can be shorter with `Linq` but for sake of simplicity as the OP is new programmer lets keep it this way.

### Edit

Now things are more clarified, the answer is no, u cant do that the way you did it, if you want to select a control based on a variable value (Which is fine in certain circumstances) , thats fine, but you have to do somthing like I showed in above code, i.e. iterate through all controls and check if the name is equal to your desire.
The fact is your code goes through a compile progress and for compiler the acceptable name of a control for example,  is  the actuall text you written there, not a combination of variables that may produce the same name, why? Because variables dont get their value until you run your code and that is after you compiled your code and without correct name compiler fails.

Comment: Edited original, please see section below EDIT1

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It wasn't something I pursued, it just hit me today if at all it was possible. Marked as solution as it is closest it can get, thank you!